# R data.table "no common type"

Tags: r, data.table, bigdata

I'm trying to use data.table on a large dataset, but to test things out, I've created a sub-datatable (that only had a few rows). When I run the code on my sub-datatable, everything works correctly, but when I try and run things on my large dataset, it doesn't work. Edit: I've made the sub-datatable larger, and now it gives the same error as before.

In general, I've created a custom function that calculates a value based on another column.

```
all_poss[,scores:=list(custom_func(alloc_opt)),by=1:nrow(all_poss)]
```

As mentioned earlier, I created a small "sub-datatable" called `testdf` that contains the first 2 rows of `all_poss`. When I run the command...

```
testdf[,scores:=list(custom_func(alloc_opt)),by=1:nrow(testdf)]
```

...the function runs fine and I get the output column I expect. However, when I run this on `all_poss`, I get the following error:

```
 Error: No common type for `VANGUARD.TARGET.2050` <double> and `scores` <character>.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I wonder if there is something unique about data.table that I'm overlooking here (when I do this using `apply` on a data.frame, it works fine, it's just incredibly slow). Have I overlooked something about data.table, and I'm causing a problem that I'm just not seeing? Or, is there a different way to achieve this (Ex: split `all_poss` by row, apply the function to each row, and then re-combine the rows to re-make the bit dataframe)?

### Thanks!

Edit1: Here is the data! I've included a new sub-datatable (testdf) that throws the same error as the large datatable (all_poss)

```
> dput(testdf)
structure(list(VANGUARD.TARGET.2050 = c(100, 90, 80), VANG.INST.500.INDEX = c(0, 
10, 20), VANG.INST.EXT.MKT = c(0, 0, 0), VANG.INST.TOT.INTL = c(0, 
0, 0), `VANG.PRIMECAP.ADM.(VPMAX)` = c(0, 0, 0), `VANGUARD.WINDSOR.ADM.(VWNEX)` = c(0, 
0, 0), `DFA.US.SM.CAP.VALUE.(DFSVX)` = c(0, 0, 0), `VANG.EXPLORER.ADM.(VEXRX)` = c(0, 
0, 0), `VANG.INTL.GROWTH.ADM.(VWILX)` = c(0, 0, 0), `VANGUARD.INTL.VALUE.(VTRIX)` = c(0, 
0, 0), `DODGE.&.COX.BALANCED` = c(0, 0, 0), `PIM.ALL.ASSET.INST.(PAAIX)` = c(0, 
0, 0), BAYER.STABLE.VALUE = c(0, 0, 0), `PIM.INTL.BD.US$H.I.(PFORX)` = c(0, 
0, 0), alloc_opt = 1:3), row.names = c(NA, -3L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000001111ef0>, class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

```
> dput(investments_long)
structure(list(ID = c("VANGUARD.TARGET.2050", "VANGUARD.TARGET.2050", 
"VANGUARD.TARGET.2050", "VANGUARD.TARGET.2050", "VANGUARD.TARGET.2050", 
"VANG.INST.500.INDEX", "VANG.INST.500.INDEX", "VANG.INST.500.INDEX", 
"VANG.INST.500.INDEX", "VANG.INST.500.INDEX", "VANG.INST.EXT.MKT", 
"VANG.INST.EXT.MKT", "VANG.INST.EXT.MKT", "VANG.INST.EXT.MKT", 
"VANG.INST.EXT.MKT", "VANG.INST.TOT.INTL", "VANG.INST.TOT.INTL", 
"VANG.INST.TOT.INTL", "VANG.INST.TOT.INTL", "VANG.INST.TOT.INTL", 
"VANG.PRIMECAP.ADM.(VPMAX)", "VANG.PRIMECAP.ADM.(VPMAX)", "VANG.PRIMECAP.ADM.(VPMAX)", 
"VANG.PRIMECAP.ADM.(VPMAX)", "VANG.PRIMECAP.ADM.(VPMAX)", "VANGUARD.WINDSOR.ADM.(VWNEX)", 
"VANGUARD.WINDSOR.ADM.(VWNEX)", "VANGUARD.WINDSOR.ADM.(VWNEX)", 
"VANGUARD.WINDSOR.ADM.(VWNEX)", "VANGUARD.WINDSOR.ADM.(VWNEX)", 
"DFA.US.SM.CAP.VALUE.(DFSVX)", "DFA.US.SM.CAP.VALUE.(DFSVX)", 
"DFA.US.SM.CAP.VALUE.(DFSVX)", "DFA.US.SM.CAP.VALUE.(DFSVX)", 
"DFA.US.SM.CAP.VALUE.(DFSVX)", "VANG.EXPLORER.ADM.(VEXRX)", "VANG.EXPLORER.ADM.(VEXRX)", 
"VANG.EXPLORER.ADM.(VEXRX)", "VANG.EXPLORER.ADM.(VEXRX)", "VANG.EXPLORER.ADM.(VEXRX)", 
"VANG.INTL.GROWTH.ADM.(VWILX)", "VANG.INTL.GROWTH.ADM.(VWILX)", 
"VANG.INTL.GROWTH.ADM.(VWILX)", "VANG.INTL.GROWTH.ADM.(VWILX)", 
"VANG.INTL.GROWTH.ADM.(VWILX)", "VANGUARD.INTL.VALUE.(VTRIX)", 
"VANGUARD.INTL.VALUE.(VTRIX)", "VANGUARD.INTL.VALUE.(VTRIX)", 
"VANGUARD.INTL.VALUE.(VTRIX)", "VANGUARD.INTL.VALUE.(VTRIX)", 
"DODGE.&.COX.BALANCED", "DODGE.&.COX.BALANCED", "DODGE.&.COX.BALANCED", 
"DODGE.&.COX.BALANCED", "DODGE.&.COX.BALANCED", "PIM.ALL.ASSET.INST.(PAAIX)", 
"PIM.ALL.ASSET.INST.(PAAIX)", "PIM.ALL.ASSET.INST.(PAAIX)", "PIM.ALL.ASSET.INST.(PAAIX)", 
"PIM.ALL.ASSET.INST.(PAAIX)", "BAYER.STABLE.VALUE", "BAYER.STABLE.VALUE", 
"BAYER.STABLE.VALUE", "BAYER.STABLE.VALUE", "BAYER.STABLE.VALUE", 
"PIM.INTL.BD.US$H.I.(PFORX)", "PIM.INTL.BD.US$H.I.(PFORX)", "PIM.INTL.BD.US$H.I.(PFORX)", 
"PIM.INTL.BD.US$H.I.(PFORX)", "PIM.INTL.BD.US$H.I.(PFORX)"), 
    metric = c("X10yrOrLOF_return", "exp_ratio", "mgsr_ratings_out_of_5", 
    "mgsr_stdev", "intl_exp", "X10yrOrLOF_return", "exp_ratio", 
    "mgsr_ratings_out_of_5", "mgsr_stdev", "intl_exp", "X10yrOrLOF_return", 
    "exp_ratio", "mgsr_ratings_out_of_5", "mgsr_stdev", "intl_exp", 
    "X10yrOrLOF_return", "exp_ratio", "mgsr_ratings_out_of_5", 
    "mgsr_stdev", "intl_exp", "X10yrOrLOF_return", "exp_ratio", 
    "mgsr_ratings_out_of_5", "mgsr_stdev", "intl_exp", "X10yrOrLOF_return", 
    "exp_ratio", "mgsr_ratings_out_of_5", "mgsr_stdev", "intl_exp", 
    "X10yrOrLOF_return", "exp_ratio", "mgsr_ratings_out_of_5", 
    "mgsr_stdev", "intl_exp", "X10yrOrLOF_return", "exp_ratio", 
    "mgsr_ratings_out_of_5", "mgsr_stdev", "intl_exp", "X10yrOrLOF_return", 
    "exp_ratio", "mgsr_ratings_out_of_5", "mgsr_stdev", "intl_exp", 
    "X10yrOrLOF_return", "exp_ratio", "mgsr_ratings_out_of_5", 
    "mgsr_stdev", "intl_exp", "X10yrOrLOF_return", "exp_ratio", 
    "mgsr_ratings_out_of_5", "mgsr_stdev", "intl_exp", "X10yrOrLOF_return", 
    "exp_ratio", "mgsr_ratings_out_of_5", "mgsr_stdev", "intl_exp", 
    "X10yrOrLOF_return", "exp_ratio", "mgsr_ratings_out_of_5", 
    "mgsr_stdev", "intl_exp", "X10yrOrLOF_return", "exp_ratio", 
    "mgsr_ratings_out_of_5", "mgsr_stdev", "intl_exp"), value = c(0.1031, 
    5e-04, 4, 12.57, 0.4, 0.1543, 1e-04, 4, 13.58, 0.01, 0.1719, 
    0.00039, 4, 18.05, 0.02, 0.095, 0.00063, 3, 15.2, 0.99, 0.1532, 
    0.0031, 3, 13.89, 0.17, 0.109, 0.002, 3, 15.29, 0.08, 0.0912, 
    0.0051, 3, 20.21, 0.03, 0.1433, 0.0034, 3, 17.7, 0.04, 0.1241, 
    0.0032, 5, 19.73, 0.85, 0.0492, 0.0038, 4, 15.25, 0.92, 0.1439, 
    0.0053, 3, 11.22, 0.05, 0.053, 0.01185, 3, 8.38, 0.3, 0.0243, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0546, 0.006, 4, 3.18, 0.65)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -70L))
```

```
> dput(norm)
structure(list(metric = c("X10yrOrLOF_return", "exp_ratio", "mgsr_ratings_out_of_5", 
"mgsr_stdev", "intl_exp"), max = c(0.1719, 0.01185, 5, 20.21, 
0.99)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

```
> dput(weightings)
structure(list(metric = c("X10yrOrLOF_return", "exp_ratio", "mgsr_ratings_out_of_5", 
"mgsr_stdev", "intl_exp"), weight = c(1, 0.5, 0.5, -0.5, 0.3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Custom function

```
custom_func <- function(alloc_opt){
  
  #THIS IS HOW YOU CALL VARIABLES IN DATATABLES
  opt <- as.numeric(as.character(alloc_opt))
  print(paste0("allocation_option_",opt))
  
  #get the different allocations for the option
  tempdf <- testdf[testdf$alloc_opt==opt]
  tempdf <- tempdf %>% pivot_longer(cols=-alloc_opt,names_to="investment",values_to="allocation")

  #incorporate the different metrics and values into tempdf (make sure items are formatted correctly)
  tempdf$investment <- gsub(" ",".",tempdf$investment)
  tempdf <- left_join(tempdf,investments_long,by=c("investment"="ID"))

  #incorporate the max values from "norm" into tempdf
  tempdf <- left_join(tempdf,norm,by=c("metric"="metric"))

  #incorporate weights from "weightings" into tempdf
  tempdf <- left_join(tempdf,weightings,by=c("metric"="metric"))

  #calculate nwa subscore for each investment/metric in tempdf
  tempdf <- tempdf %>%
    dplyr::mutate(nwa_subscore=(value/max)*(allocation/100)*weight)

  #calculate the nwa_score for each metric in tempdf
  tempdf2 <- tempdf %>%
   dplyr::group_by(metric) %>%
   dplyr::summarize(nwa_score=sum(nwa_subscore)) %>%
   dplyr::mutate(nwa_score=round(nwa_score,digits=4))

  nwa <- tempdf2$nwa_score
  nwa <- nwa[!is.na(nwa)]
  nwa <- paste(nwa,collapse="_")

  #calculate nwao_score
  nwao <- sum(tempdf$nwa_subscore,na.rm=TRUE)
  nwao <- round(nwao,digits=4)
  
  #combine nwa & nwao into one string
  all <- paste(nwa,nwao,sep="_")
  print(all)
  
  #return all the nwa and nwao scores as _-separated values
  return(as.character(all))
}
```

What I'm getting an error on:

```
testdf[,scores:=custom_func(alloc_opt),by=1:nrow(testdf)]
```

Output

```
Error: No common type for `VANGUARD.TARGET.2050` <double> and `scores` <character>.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: Can't really provide actionable help without sample data, but `data.table` (and, frankly, most *robust* functions) do not silently coerce data from one class to another. The reason that doing something similar with `apply` works is likely because it will silently coerce something from `numeric` to `character`. If that behavior is intentional, then do it beforehand. If not, then this error just saved you.

Comment: I can definitely add the dataset, I was hesitant because the original dataset is large (>1M rows), and the small data-set I created from this (just the first 2 rows of data), works just fine when I run this function. Is coercing something that is done behind-the-scenes to small datasets, but not for large datasets? If it helps, in the error message, "VANGUARD.TARGET.2050" is the left-most column in the data.table, and "scores" is the new column I'm trying to create. I get a bit confused by error messages; do I need to change "VANGUARD.TARGET.2050" to 'character' in order to run the function?

Comment: Most questions on SO do not require more than 5-20 rows (4-10 columns) of data to get the point across. To answer your concern about `data.table`, I know of nothing inherent to it that would be *causing* this unexpectedly. My guess is that `custom_func` is non-deterministic: sometimes it returns `numeric`, sometimes it returns `character`. *That* is likely the problem you need to investigate ... and we might be able to help if it is small and you post it here.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I've edited the post to contain the data needed for you to replicate. In general, the function takes a single row of data, then pulls from other reference tables to calculate some values (nwa & nwao scores), then connects them in one big character (where each number is separated by "_"), and returns that string.